# update in sql database is not work in android

Tags: android, sql

im trying to update one row from table ,but it seem doesnt updated 
(i havent error but its not updated)

class NoteDatabase

```
public class NotesDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final String DB_name ="dataNotes.db";
public NotesDataBase(Context context) {
    super(context,DB_name, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table Notes (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title TEXT,detail TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Notes");
}
public boolean insertData(String title,String detail){
    SQLiteDatabase database=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("title",title);
    contentValues.put("detail",detail);
    long result=database.insert("Notes",null,contentValues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else return true;
}

public boolean updateData(String id,String title,String detail){
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("ID",id);
    contentValues.put("title",title);
    contentValues.put("detail",detail);

    database.update("Notes",contentValues,"ID=?",new String[]{id});
    return true;

}
public boolean deleteData(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase database=getWritableDatabase();
    database.delete("Notes","ID=?",new String[]{id});
    return true;
}
public ArrayList  getAllRecord(){
    ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList<NotesData>();
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getReadableDatabase();  //the error is here
    Cursor res=database.rawQuery("select * from Notes",null);
    res.moveToFirst();



    while (res.isAfterLast()==false){
        String ID=res.getString(0);
        String title=res.getString(1);
        String detail=res.getString(2);
        arrayList.add(new NotesData(ID,title,detail));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return arrayList;

}
public NotesData getOneRow(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res=db.rawQuery("select * from Notes WHERE id = "+id,null);
    if (res!=null)
        res.moveToFirst();

    NotesData notes=new NotesData(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("ID"))
            ,res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("title"))
            ,res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("detail")));
    return notes;

}
```

}

in the following class im using update method:

```
public class UpdateShowEditNote extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText title,detail;
String myTitle ;
String myDetail;
String ID;

NotesDataBase db=new NotesDataBase(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_show_edit_note);
    title= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title1);
    detail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.detail1);
    myTitle=getIntent().getStringExtra("title_key");
    myDetail=getIntent().getStringExtra("detail_key");
    ID=getIntent().getStringExtra("ID_key");


    title.setText(myTitle); //get title and detail from listview
    detail.setText(myDetail);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if((myTitle.equals(title.getText().toString()))&&(myDetail.equals(detail.getText().toString()))) {


        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else
    {
      boolean res=  db.updateData(ID,myTitle,myDetail);
        if(res==true)
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"the changed has been saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
}
```

class NoteData

```
public class NotesData {
private String ID,title ,detail;
NotesData(){}
NotesData(String ID,String title ,String detail){
    this.title=title;
    this.detail=detail;
    this.ID=ID;
}

NotesData(String title ,String detail){
    this.title=title;
    this.detail=detail;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDetail() {
    return detail;
}

public void setDetail(String detail) {
    this.detail = detail;
}
```

}

how can it work(database.update)??

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure that everything else is set up correctly, but if you want to modify data, you will need to call `getWritableDatabase` instead of `getReadableDatabase`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()

Comment: In the logs, do you see either an exception/stack trace or any warning messages that seem relevant?

Comment: E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length     ... i dont know if that is related

Comment: I think you also need to call `insert` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues) instead of `update`. Update only modifies an existing row, whereas insert will create a new one. Let me know if it works, and I'll update the answer!

Comment: I want to update row, not insert, however the insert method is work without any problem

Comment: How are you verifying this? Are you sure that you are updating the correct id, and that the values are actually different? :) Any more context you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not totally sure if this is the problem, but in your schema you have an integer `ID` column, whereas everywhere else you're representing it as a string. It's possible that the conversion is somehow causing the equality check to fail. I would try changing all your id fields (in `NotesData`, `UpdateShowEditNote`, etc) to integers as well.

Comment: i did it ,not working :( ... however i checked for the ID that reach to _update_ method by toast and gave me correct result (as expected) . what ur opinion :(

Answer (score 0):

**Original:**

Try:

```
  SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWriteableDatabase();
```

**EDIT:**

I tried your DB code with a simple Activity ... your Update funciton works fine for me:

**NotesDataBase onCreat():**

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table Notes (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title TEXT,detail TEXT)");
    db.close();
    insertData("Title1" ,"Detail1");
}
```

**Activity:**

```
public class UpdateShowEditNote extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView title,detail;

final NotesDataBase db=new NotesDataBase(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_show_edit_note);
    title= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title1);
    detail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail1);
    Button button = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                db.updateData("1", "Title2", "Detail2");

                List<NotesData> data = db.getAllRecord();
                title.setText(data.get(0).getTitle());
                detail.setText(data.get(0).getDetail());
        }
    });

    List<NotesData> data = db.getAllRecord();

    title.setText(data.get(0).getTitle());
    detail.setText(data.get(0).getDetail());
}
}
```

So I'd guess your problem is not the update call.

And corresponding to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19316940/5056601) you might not change your PRIMARY_KEY, so maybe not put the ID in contentValues for your update query.

Comment: You should explain your solutions.

Comment: getReadableDatabase only grants read access -> you can not change data storage.
Hm that's the only thing i saw, wich could be responsible for your problem. You can post more code, maybe?

Comment: i added more code ,please see the code again @fijili

Comment: I simplified your code and tried it. It works fine. i Will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

**New answer:**

I know it's not the answer to your question, but I can't crack this one either. I don't know why it's not updating. I get the same issue. But this code works. Maybe it's useful for you.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NotesDataBase myDb;
EditText editID, editTITLE, editDETAIL;
Button btnAddData;
Button btnviewAll;

Button btnviewUpdate;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> itemList;
ListView listV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDb = new NotesDataBase(this);

    editID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editID);
    editTITLE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTITLE);
    editDETAIL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDETAILS);
    btnAddData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.InsertData);
    btnviewAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getData);
    btnviewUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateButton);

    String[] items = {""};
    itemList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView, itemList);
    listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listV.setAdapter(adapter);

    AddData();
    viewAll();
    UpdateData();
}

public void UpdateData() {
    btnviewUpdate.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isUpdate = myDb.updateData(editID.getText().toString(),
                            editTITLE.getText().toString(),
                            editDETAIL.getText().toString());
                    if (isUpdate == true)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

public void AddData() {
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editTITLE.getText().toString(),
                            editDETAIL.getText().toString());
                    if (isInserted == true)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

public void viewAll() {
    btnviewAll.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    itemList.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Cursor c = myDb.getAllRecord();

                    while (c.moveToNext()) {
                        String _id = c.getString(0);
                        String title = c.getString(1);
                        String details = c.getString(2);
                        adapter.add(_id + ": " + title + " " + details);
                        listV.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    myDb.close();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

}

XML for Main Activity

```
<Button
    android:text="Get data"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/getData" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="ID"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editID"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getData"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="TITLE"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTITLE"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editID"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="DETAILS"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editDETAILS"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTITLE"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editDETAILS"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/list"/>

<Button
    android:text="Update data"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/updateButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Insert data"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editID"
    android:id="@+id/InsertData" />
```

XML for the list:

```
 <TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

And the NotesDataBase

```
public class NotesDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DB_name = "dataNotes.db";

public NotesDataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_name, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table Notes (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title TEXT,detail TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Notes");
}

public boolean insertData(String title, String detail) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("title", title);
    contentValues.put("detail", detail);
    long result = database.insert("Notes", null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else return true;
}

public boolean updateData(String id, String title, String detail) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("ID", id);
    contentValues.put("title", title);
    contentValues.put("detail", detail);

    database.update("Notes", contentValues, "ID=?", new String[]{id});
    return true;

}

//I turned this into a cursor method, because I'm familiar with it
public Cursor getAllRecord() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = database.rawQuery("select * from Notes", null);
    return res;
}
```

}

**Old and wrong answer:** (with correction for typo):

At a first glance I'd say: remove the double quotation marks around Notes;

```
database.update(Notes,contentValues,"ID=?",new String[]{id});
```

Let me know whether it works.

Comment: must be double cuotation bro because it take String

Comment: I agree with @fijili that the problem doesn't appear to be in your update call. If my edited solution is not helpful, can you give us an idea on what you want your architecture to look like?